# SQL: Adding Aliases to a column value

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables, one is a set of real names, the other has a collection of aliases for those people. I want to select from the real name table, but include all of the values in the alias table for each value in the realname. How would I go about this?

```
CREATE TABLE PEOPLE(
  ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME VARCHAR(64)
);
INSERT INTO PEOPLE(NAME)VALUES('BRUCE'),('CLARK'),('STEVE');

CREATE TABLE ALIASES(
  ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  PID INTEGER REFERENCES PEOPLE(ID),
  NAME VARCHAR(64)
);
INSERT INTO ALIASES(PID,NAME)VALUES
(1,'BATMAN'),(2,'SUPERMAN'),(3,'CAPTAIN AMERICA'),(1,'THE DARK KNIGHT');
```

I would like the result to look the below, so that I can do a full text search on that column value.

```
> SELECT NAME FROM PEOPLEALIASED;
NAME
-----
BRUCE BATMAN THE DARK KNIGHT
CLARK SUPERMAN
STEVE CAPTAIN AMERICA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with [`string_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html):

```
select  p.name || string_agg(a.name, ' ')
from    people p
join    aliases a
on      p.id = a.pid
group by
        p.name
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/87e25/5/0)

Comment: Is there some way to concocnate the 2 columns this returns into 1 column?

Comment: change it from p.name, string_agg(a.name,', ') to be p.name || string_agg(a.name,' ')